# enumerating recursively all coordinates in a n*m rectangle to check for all coordinates if a rectangle fits in horizontally or vertically python

Tags: python

how should I make my check for conflict work and go through all possible ways so as to return the optimal way??

objectiv: return optimal coordinates solution without conflict for the instance e.g (0,0) , (0,2)..

what we have an example (n*m)=(5*5):

- A for Vertically: height=a=3, width=b=2
- B for horizontally:height=a=2, width=b=3
- if A=(0,0) means: e.g (0,0) till (0+height,O+width) must fit in n*m and must not be occupied
- coordinates={'C': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]}
- so i want to test as from (0,0) if A or B passes recursively and return an optimal solution at the end, i have tried this in form of a tree it didn't work, since i always need to check on already solved solutions to know if next coordinate fits or not

```
dic= dict({"A": [], "B": []})
p={'C': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]}
def enumOptimal(p,dic,ii):
    if A : dic['A'].append(A)
           enumOptimal(next p,dic,ii)
    if B : dic['B'].append(B) 
           enumOptimal(next p,dic,ii) 
    enum(next Point, dic)#in case neither A nor B fits
    if ii >len(p): print dic
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, can you reformulate in simpler terms? What does the rectangle coordinates need to "fit"? What is the definition of the optimal way, based on which metric? What is the "conflict"?

Comment: i want to pack rectangles in such a way that the total number of rectangles in n*m is maximum,

Comment: @Louis Lac conflict here means: for every coordinate i need to check if A or B passes in the Rectangle(or Matrix) n*m. Area= (n*m)/(height*weight) approximately gives us the maximum number of A's and B's we can place in the matrix. So you could think of this like a matrix``` m=[  [0 for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n) ]``` where A or B can be placed without overlap

Comment: so i need to adopt the algorithm so that it tests all possible combinations A , B or Nothing for the 25 coordinates in the example , 3^^25 and then return an optimal solution. The algorithm should work fast since for instance at point (0,0) A fits all points in between (0,0) till (0+height,0+width) will not be returned as possible placement points

Comment: What are A and B? Coordinate? A rectangle?

Comment: e.g A=(0,0) is the start coordinate for the rectangle, we only store start-left-coordinates. if 0+height<=n and 0+width<=m: then it fits and if it doesn't falls in between another placement point then we append to dic